# Entity Framework inheritance and many to many mapping

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, inheritance, stored-procedures, many-to-many

This is tehnically two problems but I think I allready know the solution to the first but I'll post it here just to check.

I'm using Entity Framework 6, and am building the model database first way. In the database all significan interactions (inserting and modifying) are handled through stored procedures (mainly so I can do additional database side perimision checks).

First problem is that I'm trying to build a School's database. I have two tables Profesors and Students. I also have an aditional tabla called PersonalData that contains personal data info like names, surnames and such. Profesor and student tables are in 1:0.1 relationships with PersonalData, meaning for every single Profesor there has to be a PersonalData record. Same with the students. Not every record in PersonalData must be a student or a Profesor, some of them are parents.

At first I tried to implement this in EF as an TPT inheritance, but problems may arise if a Student becomes at some point a Professor. Due to the way EF handles inheritance the PersonalData collection could easily contain TWO entities with the same ID.

I have googled this a bit and have found out that using inheritance in these kind of cases is impossible, and that I'll probably need to go back to accessing Personal Data throgh relationships, but that will cause certain possible problem due to the fact that now I'll have to manually make sure a PersonalRecord is added for every Student/Professor. Unless anybody has any better idea?

Second problem is due to the fac that I'm using stored procedures for inserting and updating data. I also have fiew many to many relationships in the DB, and when I import the tables many to many related, I see no way to map that relationship (it's table) to a procedure.

So does anyone know how to map many to many relationships to stored procedures in the Model Designer?

Answer (score 0):

As to Many to Many mapping to stored procedures, it seems that it's impossible for now. What you can is attach INSTEAD OF triggers to the JOIN table, or a view representing that table. The methid using a view causes problems however since EF treats views as readonly, so you'll need to manually edit the emdx and change the view's type from view to table. This will make EF treat view as a table. Also if you are using the view method, EF model designer won't turn the view representing cross table into an association automatically. You'll have to add the assoc manually, map it manually and than delete the view entity so it doesn't cause an error since two things would be mapping to the same object (association and the entity).